# Select record by given date from and date till.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I having the records as below

```
StartDate    | EndDate    | ID
---------------------------------
25-12-2016     30-12-2016    0 
01-01-2017     05-01-2017    1
10-01-2017     12-01-2017    2
01-02-2017     05-02-2017    3
```

By given selecting the Date Range from **02-01-2017** till **11-01-2017** , How do we select the record Startdate n EndDate that is fall on between the Date Range given as expected?

Would like to expect table result as below

```
StartDate    | EndDate    | ID
------------------------------
01-01-2017     05-01-2017    1
10-01-2017     12-01-2017    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically you are asking how to check if two date ranges overlap.
The way to do this is to check that one starts before the other ends, while the other starts before one ends. You can see a visualization in the [overlap](/questions/tagged/overlap) [tag wiki.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info)

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT StartDate, EndDate, ID
FROM YourTable
WHERE StartDate <= '11-01-2017'
AND EndDate >= '02-01-2017'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query,

```
DECLARE @V_START_DATE   DATETIME = '2017-01-02' 
        ,@V_END_DATE    DATETIME = '2017-01-11' 

SELECT  *
FROM    @TABLE
WHERE   StartDate   BETWEEN @V_START_DATE AND @V_END_DATE
    OR  EndDate     BETWEEN @V_START_DATE AND @V_END_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Query

```
SELECT * FROM DateRanges
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN '02-01-2017' and '11-01-2017'
OR ENDdate  BETWEEN '02-01-2017' and '11-01-2017'
```